# Understanding Rosenlicht's proof that intervals are connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

The following is the proof given in Rosenlicht's Introduction to Analysis for the intuitive fact that intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are connected. Unfortunately I am having some trouble understanding a step in his proof, namely the fact that $A_1$ and $B_1$ are disjoint open subsets; it seems to me that they should be half open half closed instead. It therefore appears that I have misunderstood something, so could you please take a look and help me out? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \cap  B = \emptyset$ then

\begin{align*}
&[a,b] \bigcap \big(A \cap B\big) &= \emptyset\\
\implies &\big([a,b] \cap A\big) \bigcap \big([a,b] \cap B\big) &= \emptyset\\
\implies &A_1 \cap A_2 &= \emptyset
\end{align*}

$A_1$, and $A_2$ are therefore disjoint open sets of $[a,b]$ for the **subspace topology**, as intersection between open sets ($A$ and $B$) and $[a,b]$.

> **Remainder**: Let $A \subset X$ with $X$ topological space. We define the subspace topology on $A$ such that $U \subset A$ is an open set of $A$ if there exists an open set $V \subset X$ such that $U = A \cap V$.

Comment: But $[a,b]$ is not an open set. It is a very closed set.

Comment: $[a,b]$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ indeed. But here, we're taking about the **subspace topology**.

Comment: Thank you but I am not familiar with subspace topology, Rosenlicht has not explained that up until connectedness.

Comment: You probably wanted to say that $U=A\cap V$

Comment: @user160738 Fixed ;)

Comment: @JohnK You must have missed it then. Take a look in the Index ;)

Comment: Already did, not there.

Comment: @JohnK Paragraph &1, remark (3) ;). The word "subspace topology" is not used though.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help.